# MySQL Query Optimization with subqueries and JOINs on large database

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query-optimization, sql-optimization

I am new here and have already searched the whole internet for a solution. If I missed something, please let me know!

I use a MySQL MariaDB with several **million** entries. My query results in timeouts. Even increasing the timeout does not help. The goal of the query is to retrieve the relevant entries per year. My query must join a total of 5 tables. (Unfortunately the structure of the DB is predefined, there is little I can change).

Below you find the affected query. The **date is stored as varchar**, that's why I use the **LIKE %** operator. Unfortunately I don't have the permissions to change it.

```
    SELECT
    spCit.spPN,
    spCit.ipc1,
    spCit.ipc2,
    tbl_patinfo.pn
FROM
    tbl_patinfo
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT
        spIPC.spPN,
        spIPC.ipc1,
        spIPC.ipc2,
        tbl_patcit.pc_pn AS spDocNr
    FROM
        tbl_patcit
    INNER JOIN(
        SELECT DISTINCT
            tbl_ipc.pn AS spPN,
            tbl_ipc.value AS ipc1,
            tbl_ipc.main_cl AS ipc2
        FROM
            tbl_ipc
        RIGHT JOIN(
            SELECT
                tbl_sp.sp_CompanyAlias,
                OrgName,
                infoPN
            FROM
                tbl_sp
            INNER JOIN(
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    tbl_patinfo.pn AS infoPN,
                    tbl_adr.orgname AS OrgName
                FROM
                    tbl_patinfo
                LEFT JOIN tbl_adr ON tbl_patinfo.pn = tbl_adr.pn
                WHERE
                    tbl_patinfo.pub LIKE "%2004"
            ) AS PatPerYear
        ON
            tbl_sp.sp_CompanyAlias = PatPerYear.Orgname
        ) AS spPatents
    ON
        tbl_ipc.pn = spPatents.infoPN
    ) AS spIPC
ON
    tbl_patcit.pn = spIPC.spPN
) AS spCit
ON
    tbl_patinfo.docnr = spCit.spDocNr
```

**Note:** The whole query works if I don't make the last JOIN (**tbl_patinfo.docnr = spCit.spDocNr)**. So it is probably because of this step.

[Explain Select of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWr8t.png)

Thanks in advance for your help. If I can provide any further information, please let me know.

### **---EDIT---**

So I managed to change the date type and now I am able to perform the query **for a limit of 50 rows**. But without limit I still get a timeout (over 7000s processing time).

I also reduced the VARCHAR(255) on the indexes where ever I could. Not sure whether this has an impact, but this reduced the key_len (see latest explain select).
Here is the new code:

```
 SELECT
        spCit.spPN,
        spCit.ipc1,
        spCit.ipc2,
        tbl_patinfo.pn
    FROM
        tbl_patinfo
    INNER JOIN(
        SELECT
            spIPC.spPN,
            spIPC.ipc1,
            spIPC.ipc2,
            tbl_patcit.pc_pn AS spDocNr
        FROM
            tbl_patcit
        INNER JOIN(
            SELECT DISTINCT
                tbl_ipc.pn AS spPN,
                tbl_ipc.value AS ipc1,
                tbl_ipc.main_cl AS ipc2
            FROM
                tbl_ipc
            RIGHT JOIN(
                SELECT
                    tbl_sp.sp_CompanyAlias,
                    OrgName,
                    infoPN
                FROM
                    tbl_sp
                INNER JOIN(
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                        tbl_patinfo.pn AS infoPN,
                        tbl_adr.orgname AS OrgName
                    FROM
                        tbl_patinfo
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_adr ON tbl_patinfo.pn = tbl_adr.pn
                    WHERE
                        YEAR(tbl_patinfo.pub) = 2004
                ) AS PatPerYear
            ON
                tbl_sp.sp_CompanyAlias = PatPerYear.Orgname
            ) AS spPatents
        ON
            tbl_ipc.pn = spPatents.infoPN
        ) AS spIPC
     ON
        tbl_patcit.pn = spIPC.spPN
    ) AS spCit
    ON
        tbl_patinfo.docnr = spCit.spDocNr
```

[Here's the new EXPLAIN select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir7h0.png)

**I'm very thankful for any idea!**

Comment: I don't understand anything about the query. But with millions of results, the only way are simple queries with joins of indexed fields or reduce the number of results to cross. You can't edit structure but you can create new tables or temporany tables to preprocess and decompose into more small problems the query

Comment: Yes sorry, the query could be confusing. My first approach was to split the query into views and use the temptable algorithm, but that didn’t work either. 
I also put an index on both columns of the last join (tbl_patinfo.docnr, tbl_patcit.pc_pn)

Comment: "don't have the permissions to change it" -- warm up your resume.

Answer (score 0):

You are out of luck on that one. A LIKE '%...' filter is unindexable. There are things you could do about it, e.g. create a dynamic column, or a non-dynamic column maintained by a trigger, that contains the reverse of the tbl_patinfo.pub, and then instead of
    tbl_patinfo.pub LIKE '%2004'
you could say
    tbl_patinfo.revpub LIKE '4002%'

Comment: Thanks Gordan, I’ll try that. I know that the % in front of the string causes lots of performance issues, but didn’t think of your idea.